# Socket PHP hangs on fgets

Tags: php, sockets, freeze, fgets

I have server and client application in JAVA, what working with this server. On first look, it's no problems - JAVA uses `socket.getInputStream()` for receiving data and `socket.getOutputStream()` for sending data.

I need to write same client on PHP. All examples from manuals didn't help me. I can succesfully connect to server, but when i trying to read something - page hangs. For example:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client($addr, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        var_dump(fgets($fp, 1024));
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This code hangs even without while.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does your server really send bytes?

```
fgets($fp, 1024)
```

returns, if one of these conditions happens:

**- EOF or newline received**

**- 1024-1 bytes read**

or the **far side closed the connection**.

If these conditions do not happen, the call blocks.

How about changing 1024 to a lower number or use fgetc()?

Comment: By my case, I have a response with a windows end line (i.e 0xd followed by 0xa -\r\n-)  doing character by character as @StepAp mentions and doing a break within body "while" when 0xa is found solves the problem.